# How to add subview with progressbar (spinner) inside listView?

Tags: android

i want to display a view with progressbar on top of listView. i want to add this view inside listView, not in listView item but on top layer of listView.
i have a subclass extending  listView and onSetAdapter, while the listView is refreshing, i want to display this progress view from within that subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in a few different ways. In my opinion the best one would be to have a `RelativeLayout` with your listview and overlapping progress bar. Show/hide the progress bar whenever you set the adapter. For a smoother and better looking effect you should do something similar to the [crossfading two views](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html) example on the developer website.

Comment: CustomListView extends ListView {
onSetAdapter(){ 
//display progress bar 
//addView(child);overlap on listview //maybe i have no idea how to do this.

}
}